# Would it be okay to share Firefox's user.js between Linux and Windows?

Tags: firefox, symbolic-link

Would it be okay to share Firefox's user.js between Linux and Windows (using a symbolic link in Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, depending on how much is in there. I share pretty much my entire profile across OSes in this manner. Not that it's the recommended route by any means - that would be by using [Weave](http://mozillalabs.com/weave/), though I guess that wouldn't work here.

Comment: Anybody have anything to add?